# The navbar is overlaying the main content of the site

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a transparent navbar which always keeps overlaying the main content.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- <script src="index.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header_main">
        <div id="d1">
            <h1 id="h1_title_responsive">YASH</h1>
        </div>
        <ul id="ul_nav">
            <li class="li_nav" id="li1"><a href="#" class="a_img"><img src="logo.png" id="logo_img"></a></li>
            <li class="li_nav" id="li2"><a href="index.html" class="a_text">Home</a></li>
            <li class="li_nav" id="li3"><a href="#" class="a_text">About</a></li>
            <li class="li_nav" id="li4"><a href="#" class="a_text">Contact</a></li>
            <h1 id="h1_title">YASH</h1>
            <li id="search_li"><input name="search" id="search_box" placeholder="Search this website" type="text"></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div id="d2">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos ipsam et quam eum placeat consequatur iure at rerum? Necessitatibus numquam facilis, fugiat non eum ipsum. Aperiam maxime provident harum quia!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa excepturi a nihil laudantium corporis fugit quisquam enim natus facilis dolor. Vitae quibusdam blanditiis atque, eligendi architecto hic repellat amet accusantium!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea fugit enim natus? Aspernatur libero alias unde veniam cumque impedit cum corrupti facere consectetur molestiae laudantium, asperiores esse quis, autem saepe
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header_main{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    background: red;
}
.li_nav{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0.9vh 1vw;
    font-size: large;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.a_text:hover{
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
#li1{
    color: white;
}
#logo_img{
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
}
#ul_nav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
}
#h1_title{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#d1{
    display: none;
}
#h1_title_responsive{
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    position:relative;
    width: 100vw;
}
#search_box{
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 2em;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bolder;
    width: 170%;
}
#search_li{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 75%;
    width: 12.5%;
}
#d2{
    height: 1000vh;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    #h1{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #d1{
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the issue:

[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgWoL.png

and in my css the #d2 is 1000vh because I want the navbar to work perfectly even when scrolling

Comment: _"stack overflow is telling me that"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" so I am adding these fake details:"_ - it did _not_ ask you to add random gibberish, so please do not add random gibberish.

Comment: Come on bruh i have provided a lot of details it is enough to understand the problem and if still don't get it then just see other people who have answered the questions and try to figure out.Finding the problem is not issue finding answer is the issue

Answer (score 0):

The navbar `position: fixed` means that the navbar element is removed from the flow of the document.

You can find the full explanation of what `position: fixed` does here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.

To prevent the navbar from covering the main content, you have to add either some padding or margin above the content.

```
#d2{
   padding-top: // height of the navbar + some extra
}
```

Comment: the height of navbar is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

The navbar has position fixed. Read more here: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.)

Fix this by adding a height to your navbar.

Example:

```
#header_main{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px; /*set to your own*/
}
```

Comment: can't set my own the navbar is responsive and the height keeps changing